# Plupload unable to upload files over 940kb, this is the issue with larger files

Tags: dom, element, plupload

When uploading files with pluploader the small files are uploaded without issue, but as soon as the files are chunked the script loses the actual file name which results in the following error:

> `Failed to open input stream`

So, I need a way to pass the actual filename from the HTML form to the upload php. There is a line in the `custom.html` file that says:

```
browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass an id...
container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
```

In the DOM the element I need is `file.name` in this script part

```
FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
    plupload.each(files, function(file) {
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + 
        '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
    });
```

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this? I have tried accessing the element with java and isset but without any success.

Comment: Did you try setting the `send_file_name` attribute to true in the constructor? Reference: https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Uploader

Comment: Yes but that version creates the file but leaves a name that it creates form its own ID, it begins with file_*********  so it loses the original file name but chunks the large file correctly. So with that version I still need to obtain the original file name from the DOM or button

Comment: I see. In that case you may need to set `uniqueNames` to false in the same constructor. If that doesn't work, here is a nice article on how to get the original file name while chunking: https://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1259.

Comment: as I metioned in my post the  document.getElementById has the element file.name that is the one I want, do you mknow how i can pass that to upload.php?

Comment: this line in php works,but it uploads the whole file into the vaiable when I only need the original title, is there a way to use get contents to access the file title?  $post = file_get_contents('php://input');

Answer (score 0):

In plupload there is a main upload script called upload.php and this is the code that renames the uploaded file to a meaningless code i. e.
file_6272e003ad256 and this is the code in upload.php that renames that file id name

```
// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
```

So, search this file for the word filename

```
    // What to look for
$search = 'filename';
// Read from file
$lines = file('file_6272e003ad256');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    echo $line;
}
```

Then extract the phrase between the double quotes and this is the filename to rename the file with

```
rename($filePath, $original_filename);
```